# Excel VBA - UsingVBA to create a new, formatted workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write the last part of my program and I need to pull data from an Access document and print it into a new Workbook.

To start, I will be taking the names of product Suppliers and creating a Worksheet with each suppliers name, then I want to be looping through each sheet and printing the products from each supplier that were ordered.

I'm really struggling with wrapping my head around how to open a new workbook and print in my info.

Comment: I can give you this link: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/974148-create-excel-spreadsheet-using-vba-code-access.html Hope it helps you

Comment: Some years ago I created a demo Access Project that created an Excel workbook.  You are welcome to a copy.  If you look at my profile you will see an email address.  Send me a message and I will email you a copy.

Comment: To add a small correction to the otherwise solid code posted by Barranka, below: Presuming you have more than one row in your data table or query, you'd likely want to add rec.MoveNext just above the Loop Until .EOF line.

Answer (score 7):

As my previous answer was deleted (considered "insuficient"), I have to provide a better one.

If you want to output data from Access to Excel, you have to follow this steps:

1. Create (or open) a new workbook
2. Read your data
3. Write your data to the workbook
4. Format the data in the workbook

I will focus on the data output, and leave the formatting out (the data part is the complicated one... formatting is easy)

First, you need to enable the Excel objects in your Access file: Tools Menu > References. Find the *Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library* and activate the checkbox. Now you have the full Excel library at your service :-)

Now is the time for the data crunching. I will asume that you need to create a new workbook:

```
public sub createExcelFile()
    dim XL as Excel.Application, WB as Excel.Workbook, WKS as Excel.Worksheet
    dim db as DAO.database, rec as DAO.recordset, f as DAO.field
    dim i as integer, j as integer

    ' Prepare your Excel stuff
    Set XL = new Excel.Application
    XL.Visible = True
    Set WB = XL.Workbooks.Add 
    WB.Activate
    Set WKS = WB.ActiveSheet ' Default: The first sheet in the newly created book

    ' Read your data here
    set db = currentdb()
    set rec = db.openrecordset("tblSampleData")

    ' A simple table that will show the data from rec
    ' i and j will be the coordiantes of the active cell in your worksheet
    with rec
        .movefirst

        ' The table headers
        i = 1
        j = 1
        for each f in .fields
            WKS.cells(i,j).value = f.name
            j = j + 1
        next f

        ' The table data
        do
            i = i+1
            j = 1
            for each f in .Fields
                WKS.cells(i,j).value = f.value
                j = j+1
            next f     
            .moveNext     
        loop until .EOF
    end with
end sub
```

If you want to format the cells, you can use the `WKS.cells(i,j)` (or `WKS.range(...)`) properties.

Take a look at the link I leaved before (which Siddarth Rout was kind to move to the comments).

I hope this helps you

Comment: I know that there are other techniques to read Access data... but I'm very comfortable using `DAO`... sometimes *low tech is best*

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function format(filepath, sheetname)


Set xls = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
xls.screenupdating = False
xls.displayalerts = False
xls.Visible = True
xls.workbooks.Open filepath
Set xlsdd = xls.ActiveWorkbook
```

'deleting headers

```
xls.Range("1:1").Select
xls.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

'adding one column

```
    xls.Columns("A:A").Select
   xls.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'adding 5 rows
```

'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Select

```
xls.Rows("1:5").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

'fetching rows from access and putting them into excel

```
strsql = "select top 5 " & sheetname & ".* into top5_records from " & sheetname
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
outputFileName = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\top5_records.xls"
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "top5_records",    outputFileName, True
```

'then open that excel and copy the rows

```
Set xls2 = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
xls2.screenupdating = False
xls2.displayalerts = False
xls2.Visible = True
xls2.workbooks.Open outputFileName
Set xlsdd2 = xls.ActiveWorkbook
 xls2.Rows("1:5").Select
 xls2.Selection.Copy
  xls.Cells(1, 1).Select
 xls.activesheet.Paste



     '  Dim currdb As DAO.Database
'  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
'
'  Set currdb = CurrentDb
'  Set rst = currdb.OpenRecordset(strsql) '<<<Opens query recordset via DAO
'  rst.MoveLast
'  rowsToReturn = rst.RecordCount
'  Set rng = xls.Cells(1, 1)
'  'copy specified number of records to worksheet
'
'rng.CopyFromRecordset rst, rowsToReturn '<<<Gets all records in recordset
```

'making first 6th row to be bold

```
 xls.Rows("6:6").Select
  With xls.Selection.Font
  .Bold = True
  .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 10
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
End With
```

'autofit the data

```
xls.Sheets(sheetname).Cells.Columns.autofit
xls.CutCopyMode = False
With xlsdd
.Save
.Close
End With
xls.Visible = False

Set xlsdd = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define column/row widths to a static pixel amount or auto-fit, things like bold are a pre-defined

Example

```
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

You can also make a template spreadsheet, copy the contents into the template and save as.
Your post does not indicate how much formatting actually needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of details, so I can't give you a lot of details in return.  But here's how I would do it:

1. Create a new workbook manually with two sheets
2. On one sheet, add an External Data table that returns a list of supplier's name like SELECT SupplierName FROM tblSuppliers WHERE Active=True; or something like that.
3. Create a workbook-level named range that dynamically expands with that query table
4. On the second sheet, add an External Data table like SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE SupplierName=? (This will be a parameter query).  Start that external data table in row 3
5. I row, put a combobox box that points back to the supplier list.

Now the VBA is simple

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Instead of one sheet per supplier, you'll have one sheet on which you can change the supplier.  Here are the skills you'll need

- Create an external data table
- Create a parameter query (old reference http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/ExternalData6.htm)
- Create dynamically expanding range name
- Add a combobox or data validation that points to a range on a different sheet
- That SQL above is obviously not right, but I assume you can write the correct SQL statement

You should be able to find details on all that, but if not, post another question.